# Ansible: run task with individual parameters for each server

Tags: bash, parameters, ansible

need to run task on several servers:  it would be the same pipeline, but different data on eatch server.

So, i've list of files. It must be sliced to server-number parts, each sublist pass to individual servers copy of task, than run independantly.

I don't know how to:

1. separate input list to parts
2. pass slice in server-instance task
3. organize task - it consist of couple of steps (copy to server /tmp folder, copy from server to local, remove /tmp to release disk-space). It must be another playbook, with included to my playbook? Don't know how to set couple of subtasks in one loop.

All exapmles and askes talk about runing differnt task in parallel. But i have the same task, but parametrized.
If there're no list of files as parameter, it runs trivially: just set hosts, and set task.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: rly? What code? I don't know any algorithm to separate list and run task. If i have it - there are no question to ask.

Comment: If you want to run task per server with different input, use host variables to specify the input per host. If the number of tasks per server is dynamic and there is some work-management involved, this is not a job for ansible. Write your own script to handle that. Ansible is for server _administration_, not for workload management - use docker-like things for that, kubernetes or docker and so on.

Comment: Make a file per server, and read the file with the appropriate name on each server. The name of the file becomes the parameter, or is dynamically selected by the remote server. Try something, and we'll be able to extend whichever you've chosen.

Answer (score 0):

An option to

> "run task on several servers ..., but different data on each server"

would be to [include](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html) files with different data for each server.

```
- include_vars: "{{ ansible_hostname }}.yaml"
```